# Will c++ create multiple instances of function from template with non-type parameters

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I recently learned about c++ templates and was testing them out with a matrix class:

```cpp
template<typename T>

class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix();

        int width;
        int height;

        Matrix operator*(const Matrix& rMatrix)
        Matrix operaor+(const Matrix& rMatrix)

        // other matrix operations/functions here
    private:
        T* data;
};
```

I then found that templates could take non-type parameters, allowing me to do this:

```cpp
template<typename T, int width, int height>

class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix();

        template <int width2>
        Matrix<T, width2, height> operator*(const Matrix<width2, width>7 rMatrix)

        // other matrix operations/functions here

    private:
        T* data;
};
```

I figured that the latter was probably better if you knew all the sizes you would need at compile-time, as it would generate compilation errors if the matrices were the wrong size (for the multiplication/addition operations), whereas the former forced me to check this at run-time. I was, however, worried that the compiler would be generating different functions for adding a 4x4 to a 4x4 vs a 3x3 to a 3x3 (assuming both had the same type), which would be inefficient.

So my question is this: will the compiler I'm using (g++) generate multiple functions from a template when there is a variation in a non-type parameter (in the above example, matrix width/height)?

edit/clarifications:

- the functions are not defined inline (they are in a separate .tpp file)
- by 'inefficient', I mean that (by my understanding) having these variations on the function will cause the compiled executable to be larger than it would otherwise be

Comment: It may depend on whether the functions are defined inline.

Comment: Also, why do you think it would be inefficient to define multiple functions like that? (it usually isn't)

Comment: Compile it and see what happens.

Comment: You might still forward your template functions to regular function to avoid/minimize bloating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/).

If you paste your code there and add a `main` function that uses two matrix types with different height and widths (see [here](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=dGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVCwgaW50IHdpZHRoLCBpbnQgaGVpZ2h0PgpjbGFzcyBNYXRyaXgKewogICAgcHVibGljOgogICAgICAgIE1hdHJpeCgpOwoKICAgICAgICB0ZW1wbGF0ZSA8aW50IHdpZHRoMj4KICAgICAgICBNYXRyaXg8VCwgd2lkdGgyLCBoZWlnaHQ%20IG9wZXJhdG9yKihjb25zdCBNYXRyaXg8VCwgd2lkdGgyLCB3aWR0aD4gck1hdHJpeCk7CgogICAgICAgIC8vIG90aGVyIG1hdHJpeCBvcGVyYXRpb25zL2Z1bmN0aW9ucyBoZXJlCgogICAgcHJpdmF0ZToKICAgICAgICBUKiBkYXRhOwp9OwoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7CiAgTWF0cml4PGRvdWJsZSwgMSwgMj4gTWF0cml4MTsKICBNYXRyaXg8ZG91YmxlLCAyLCAxPiBNYXRyaXgyOwp9&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) and click on the "play" button), you can observe what the compiler generates:

```
template<typename T, int width, int height>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();

    template <int width2>
    Matrix<T, width2, height> operator*(const Matrix<T, width2, width> rMatrix);

    // other matrix operations/functions here

private:
    T* data;
};

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:18 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
class Matrix<double, 1, 2>
{

public: 
  Matrix();

  template<int width2>
  Matrix<double, width2, 2> operator*(const Matrix<double, width2, 1> rMatrix);

private: 
  double * data;
public: 
  // inline constexpr Matrix(const Matrix<double, 1, 2> &) = default;
  // inline constexpr Matrix(Matrix<double, 1, 2> &&) = default;
};

#endif


/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:19 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
class Matrix<double, 2, 1>
{

public: 
  Matrix();

  template<int width2>
  Matrix<double, width2, 1> operator*(const Matrix<double, width2, 2> rMatrix);

private: 
  double * data;
public: 
  // inline constexpr Matrix(const Matrix<double, 2, 1> &) = default;
  // inline constexpr Matrix(Matrix<double, 2, 1> &&) = default;
};

#endif


int main()
{
  Matrix<double, 1, 2> Matrix1 = Matrix<double, 1, 2>();
  Matrix<double, 2, 1> Matrix2 = Matrix<double, 2, 1>();
}
```

Therefore, yes, versions for all the combinations of width and height used somewhere else in the code are generated.